# Eloquent Laravel add string to first record found

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I have a basic problem. in this foreach loop I would like to add a class of active for the very first eloquent record not for all.

```
@foreach($products as $product)
<div class="container /*firstrecord*/">
    <h1>{{ $product->title }}</h1>
</div>

@endforeach
```

output:

```
<div class="container active">
  <h1>Title 1</h1>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <h1>Title 2</h1>
</div>
```

So for the first record gets active. Would I have to set this here or in the model for product? Seems like there is an easy way but I am just missing it. Apologies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access to the index like this:

```
@foreach($products as $i => $product)
<div class="container @if($i == 0) active @endif">
    <h1>{{ $product->title }}</h1>
</div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: a bit awesome jedi thumbs up from this here hermit! ty